# How to add "/" to a certain link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web

i know how to add / to all links without /

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

but I need to do that only with one link
https://chessbraingames.com/advanced/
and do not touch another links

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Then you don't need any conditions, just match that specific path with your RewriteRule pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect this link only as follows :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(advanced)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```